# Using different InMemory databases still increases identity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm setting up my test framework to use an in memory database for the different scenarios. Each test uses a "unique" database, and each step of the test use a different context for entity framework.

Problem is, even if the tests use different "in memory" databases, and different contexts from entity framework, the identity in the database seems to increase.

For example, I have 2 unit tests:

```
[Test]
public async Task CanGetAllFromRepository()
{
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>()
        .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "CanGetAllFromRepository").Options;
    var testa = new User();
    var testb = new User();
    var testc = new User();

    using (var context = new MyContext(options))
    {
        await context.Users.AddAsync(testa);
        await context.Users.AddAsync(testb);
        await context.Users.AddAsync(testc);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    using (var context = new MyContext(options))
    {
        var repo = new UserRepository(context);
        var all = await repo.GetAllAsync();
        Assert.IsTrue(all.Count == 3);
    }
}

[Test]
public async Task CanGetByIdFromRepository()
{
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>()
        .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "CanGetByIdFromRepository").Options;
    var testa = new User();
    var testb = new User();
    var testc = new User();

    using (var context = new SalesPortalContext(options))
    {
        await context.User.AddAsync(testa);
        await context.User.AddAsync(testb);
        await context.User.AddAsync(testc);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    using (var context = new MyContext(options))
    {
        var repo = new UserRepository(context);
        var usera = await repo.GetByIdAsync(1);
        var userb = await repo.GetByIdAsync(2);
        var userc = await repo.GetByIdAsync(3);

        Assert.IsNotNull(usera);
        Assert.IsNotNull(userb);
        Assert.IsNotNull(userc);
    }
}
```

If i run the tests 1 by 1, its not an issue, but running them all together; then for the 2nd unit test the identity set ids of the users start 4, 5, 6. (When run individually, its 1, 2, 3 as expected).

## UPDATE

Ive managed to get around the issue, by manually assigning the Users their IDs, as such:

```
var testa = new User() { Id = 1 };
var testb = new User() { Id = 2 };
var testc = new User() { Id = 3 };
```

Comment: What happens if you put the tests into two separate classes?

Comment: Same issues occur

Comment: The simplest answer is that your code has a bug, so it's not actually using different memory databases after all. What have you done to verify that this is not the case?

Comment: In unit test and integration tests (which these tests are) you should always be independent of external side effects. Meaning, in this case, add users by unique names and retrieve them by these names. By assigning Id values you make your test significantly different than the real-life code.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Ive run the tests in debug mode, and manually checekd the database name.

Comment: @GertArnold I'm aware, but so far the only work-around Ive found. Regarding unit vs integration test, as per my current understanding, using inmemory databases is Microsofts recommended approach for entity framework. I did first try mocking it, but it would simply be a waste of time to configure properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an open issue on the EF github:
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/6872

Answer (score 0):

I do same thing with [XUnit](https://xunit.github.io/) and this is work for me. XUnit run the constructor for each test and there is no problem when initialize the context. Try using it